# How to stop an click event once it has the element has been clicked and then restore it when something else is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a button which creates a div. Once clicked I would like to disable the clicking event attached to the button. However I want a button in the div which when clicked turns listening for the click event back on!

So currently I am doing this:

```
$(".results").delegate(".tt", "click", function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $(this).append('<div style="position: absolute;">Example div</div>');

    });
```

How do I do this to my above code?

Thanks.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: 1.7.1 (.....................)

Comment: where is the button in the div?

Comment: @xdazz. it looks like _hard worker_ left the hard work for us... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for button you want the click event not raised use preventDefault and that button want click event raise dont write this method